# flash player ubuntu16.04

Tags: flash, pepperflash

I am using ubuntu 16.04.

I have used the commands

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

to install pepper flash but after the 2nd command I get this error

```
2017-07-08 10:41:44 (397 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/pepperflashplugin-nonfree.eWBPA0Obal/google-chrome-stable_59.0.3071.115-1_amd64.deb’ saved [60833124/60833124]

mv: cannot stat 'unpackchrome/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so': No such file or directory.
```

So how can I uninstall pepper-flashplugin in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following 3 commands as a work around for a known issue with the `pepperflashplugin` under Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Details of the nature of this issue can be seen in the link in the references below...

**References:**

- [New Pepper Flash Installer for Chromium, Firefox](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/11/new-pepper-flash-installer-for-chromium-firefox/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using an old version of the `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` package. The latest version in the Ubuntu 16.04 archive is [1.8.2ubuntu1.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/1.8.2ubuntu1.1). So upgrade to that:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Alternatively: Uninstall `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` and install [adobe-flashplugin](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html#adobe-flashplugin) instead. That way Flash will be updated with the regular package updates.